# Sample some elements from a data set in R

Tags: r

I have a data set which is imported from excel file. The name of that is "Stocks". I want to sample 4 elements from column 3 to 7.
but when I write this command:

> sample(Stocks[,3:7], 4, replace = FALSE)

it gives me 4 sample rows, not 4 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to `sample` 4 elements in total, then convert `data.frame` to a `vector` by `unlist`ing and then `sample` 4 elements out of the `vector`

```
sample(unlist(Stocks[,3:7]), 4, replace = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Sharon Updated the answer.  Assume that you have a data.frame

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You helped me so much :)